# Kmeans algorithm cyclical solution

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I am currently implementing a Kmeans clustering algorithm in R. I am not using any packages and I wrote it from scratch. I am using only one set of initial guesses, and my action upon finding an empty cluster is to select a new data point randomly and use that as the new mean for the empty cluster.

I have gathered from reading online that the solution does not always converge, and it is highly sensitive to the initial means, so when I see that behavior I am not surprised. But I am finding that sometimes my solution is actually cycling between two or more different solutions. So I have two questions associated with this observation:

1) Within a solution cycle, one solution is always better than the others as measured by the total sum of squared distances of all points to their nearest clusters. So this implies that not only does the algorithm not necessarily find the global optimum, but also it sometimes does not even improve the total sum of squared distances from one iteration to the next? I thought the solution was at least always improving...

2) What is the best way to get around this problem? Do I have to program it to recognize cycles and then select the iteration in the cycle with the lowest total distance? Or is there an easier way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: K-means has no way to create clusters, so it really depends on the initial set, but when I find a cluster becomes empty, I delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the actual objective, K-means does **not optimize the sum of total distances**.

K-means optimizes the sum of squares, i.e. $SSQ:=\sum_o \min_\mu \sum_i |x_i - \mu_i|^2$.

$i$ iterates over all dimensions, and $\mu$ are the cluster centers.

Technically, this means assigning each point to the closest cluster center by (squared or non-squared) Euclidean distance. But logically, you try to minimize above *squared deviations* across all object and dimensions.

So make sure to use the SSQ as quality measure, not some sum of distances.

Secondly, K-means clusters usually shouldn't become empty. Not if you initialize the means to be *actual data points* and avoid duplicates. Because then, this data point is bound to have a distance of 0.
K-means clusters are voronoi cells, which are convex (at least if you properly use squared euclidean, and not some random other distance function). The mean cannot move outside of this convex area for the next iteration; only within this area. So they can't collide and such things.

Comment: thank you for your explanation of the objective function Anony-Mousse. I actually meant the sum of squared distances, not the total distance, and edited my post accordingly. I think I see some significance in your explanation of Voronoi cells, but I am still not sure what that means for a cyclical solution.

Comment: Don't think of squared distances either - it won't work for arbitrary distances. It's really squared errors, across all objects and dimensions. What I meant to say is that it seems as if you have an error somewhere in your code. Adding a new cluster center must again decrease the objective function. If all your operations (and the computation of the objective function!) are valid, each must in fact decrease this objective function.

Comment: Anony Mousse, thank you for following up, you are right. I noticed that the cyclical solution was usually fairly close to a permutation of the clusters, which led me to the bug in my code.

Comment: One final note: My K-means algorithm is now converging every time. However, I am still noticiing that the total squared distances over all observations and dimensions does not necessarily decrease with each iteration. Does this mean I still have a bug in my code? Or is this normal behavior?

Comment: It's not supposed to increase. If it doesn't keep decreasing for a number of steps this can have multiple reasons. For example, numerical precision, or unstable assignments. Don't reassign objects to other clusters if both clusters have the exact same distance, unless you can still guarntee convergence then.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "if it doesn't keep decreasing for a number of steps"? My mean squared distance rapidly decreases in the first few iterations, and then it often increases slightly before converging. Since I don't think there is a machine precision error, I guess it must be unstable initial assignments or something else.

Comment: @Paul it should never increase (except for numerical precision issues). If it does, you have a bug in your code. However, depending on the implementation, it may take an extra iteration to compute the final assignments (assuming you use "cluster assignments no longer change" as termination criterion, which is the proper).

Comment: ok thank you, I will keep looking for the bug in my code.

Comment: Anony -Mousse, to follow up on this, I decided to change my K-Means algorithm so that the cluster assignment and recalculation of means steps are done for each observation individually. I heard that this gives a better solution, and I also found that while it was slightly more difficult to write, it was easier to debug than the classic k-means algorithm.

Comment: How did you do it beforehand? Do a 1NN join on k-d-trees for acceleration?

Comment: erm.. sorry I am not very up on the terminology. Before, the main cycle of the algorithm was "calculate nearest centroid for all observations, and then use these new clusterings to relculate means, then repeat." The difference being that I would wait until I was completely done with 1 cycle to recalculate means, instead of continually updating them within the cycle.

Comment: Lloyds algorithm is assigning all, then recompute the mean for all. MacQueens variant is updating the mean after each step. Most likely, the second one needs more CPU, but fewer iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question already has an accepted answer, I would like to address the yet unadressed problem of a possible non-convergence of k-means.

This can indeed occur due to ties and cyclical assignemnt of ties to different clusters. To avoid this issue, you must always use the same deterministic tie breaking, e.g., always assign ties to the cluster with teh smaller cluster label.